# SyntaxError invalid syntax when running Crontab in Python 3.8

Tags: python

I'm a newbie at this. I'm trying to use Crontab to periodically run a python script to control a stepper motor. When I run 'stepper_motor_cron.py' in terminal,I keep getting the SyntaxError below.

```
    File "stepper_motor_cron.py", line 4
        * * * * * cd /bleary83/Documents example1.py
          ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm practicing use of Crontab with the 'example1.py' script below. I believe the problem is in designating where the file 'example1.py' is located in the Crontab script. I've tried many variations in the path but invariably come up with the syntax error message.

I can run the 'example1.py' in terminal and I get the correct info in the 'append.txt' file.

I've found crontab in the usr/bin directory.

```
#! /usr/bin
from crontab import CronTab
cron = CronTab()
* * * * * cd /bleary83/Documents example1.py
```

The following is the 'example1.py' script I'm trying to run to learn how
crontab works. Once I learn how crontab works, I'll try to use it to schedule running the script I have to run the stepper motor using a Rasberry Pi contoller.

```
from datetime import datetime
myFile = open('append.txt', 'a') 
myFile.write('\nAccessed on ' + str(datetime.now()))
```

Comment: It is a python file.  You cannot use cron sytanx natively in the .py file

Comment: Why do you have that cron expression in the middle of that file? That's not Python syntax, it's cron syntax. Why do you expect it to work correctly when it's not Python code?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need that library instead of your OS-supported scheduler?

Comment: I made the change you suggested and I'll give it a try when I learn how to execute crontab script files. I thought I could run them like .py scripts with 'python3 script-name'. I'll also try the suggestion by OneCricketeer about OS-supported scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just randomly drop crontab syntax into a Python file and expect it to work. You should read the [readme](https://gitlab.com/doctormo/python-crontab/) for `python-crontab` to actually see how to use it. If you had, you'd have seen that you have to set the `tab` argument of `CronTab` to your crontab expression:

```
cron = CronTab(tab="""
  * * * * * cd /bleary83/Documents example1.py
""")
```

Comment: Also worth pointing out that the remainder of the code isn't actually being scheduled